# How to set run-as role for listener instead of servlet in web.xml?

Tags: java, security, servlets, weblogic, servlet-listeners

I have Weblogic with datasource which can be used only by users with special role. That's why I have to set run-as role for every servlet in my webapp that needs to use DB. Also I need HttpSessionListener for detecting destroyed sessions, and this listener should make record in DB about the finished session. But by specification I can't set run-as role in web.xml for this listener.

Is there any way to do this without tricks? My only thought is to call URL that mapped to special servlet with set run-as section which will do the record to DB. Or I can create TimerTask in some servlet that will check List of finished sessions and do the record, but it's worse case than the servlet calling.

I hope more usual and straight solution exists.

Comment: We have encountered exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution, or a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

It seems only solution is existed.

If you have to use DB during Spring Security authentication process you need to write aspect that intercepts all calls to you DB related method in authentication manager. This aspect should use weblogic native API for setting necessary credentials for the working thread. And it's working!

Unfortunately I can not provide code example because of NDA.

Good luck!